# how to redirect registration form to another page on codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

How can I redirect to the success page when the user submit the registration form, the problem is when I submit the form it will redirect to the success view but the page says 404 not found. Is there something wrong in my code?

public function registration() {

```
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','First Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','Last Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','Confim Password','required|matches[password]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()  ) {

        $this->load->model('Registration');

        $this->Registration->create(
            ['fname' => ucfirst($_POST['fname']),
             'lname' => ucfirst($_POST['lname']), 
             'username' => ucfirst($_POST['username']),
             'password' => md5($_POST['password'])]);   

        redirect('templates/rsuccess');

    } else {
    $view_data['page_title'] = 'Register first';
    $view_data['errors'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $view_data);
    $this->load->view('auth/registration');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
}
```

Comment: redirect(base_url().'Controller/function');

Answer (score 1):

Please check my changes

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','First Name','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','Last Name','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','Confim Password','required|matches[password]');

if ($this->form_validation->run()  ) {

    $this->load->model('Registration');

    $this->Registration->create(
        ['fname' => ucfirst($_POST['fname']),
         'lname' => ucfirst($_POST['lname']), 
         'username' => ucfirst($_POST['username']),
         'password' => md5($_POST['password'])]);   

    redirect(base_url().'templates/rsuccess', 'location', 301);


} else {
$view_data['page_title'] = 'Register first';
$view_data['errors'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();

$this->load->view('templates/header', $view_data);
$this->load->view('auth/registration');
$this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 redirect('controller/function');
```

Comment: Please provide some context for your code snippet. In particular, it is currently unclear how the OP should add your snippet to his code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `redirect()`

```
redirect(base_url().'Controller/function name');
```

Comment: Please provide some context for your code snippet. In particular, it is currently unclear how the OP should add your snippet to his code.